# Authentification Scope Problems with Google Analytics API request googleAnalyticsR

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I try to make a request for Google Analytics data -> Request Status Code: 403, Error: API returned: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

> options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected =
> "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit")

It work only for the list of Google Analytics accounts. But I got this error on a Google Analytics request

> ga_results1 <-google_analytics(ga_id,
> date_range = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-31"),
> metrics = c("users","sessions"),
> dimensions = "date")

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Please edit your question and include a ful example one line isnt really enough.   Also Google Analytics data  implies that you are using the Google Analytics data api for requesting from GA4 account  It would be helpful to know which api you are accessing.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the documentation you will find that the [google analytics API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) and the [Google analytics data api GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) requires one of the following scopes in order to request report data.

[image]

Use the proper scope scope and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. But second link is 404. And i use API v3, not v4

Comment: The link has been updated.  I just gave you both APIs as it was  unclear if you were trying to retrieve data from an old google analytics account or a GA4 Google analytics account.   Answer is the same you need to use the proper scope, edit gives you edit access no read.

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry for asking, where do I set the scopes when calling from apps-script? `var myHeaders = {
  "Authorization": auth
}

var requestOptions = {
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': myHeaders,
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : rawdata, 
  'followRedirects': true,
   'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};`